# How Can multiple keywords run at a time in Robot frameowrk?

Tags: python, robotframework

I tried to use Multithreding and Multiprocessing concept but it is not working. I want to take my output in a file. Can someone please assist how to resolve this issue?

I am observing both keyword running times are not same.They are executing one by one.

from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
import threading
from multiprocessing import Process

class importABR:

```
def __init__(self):
    pass



def abr1_keyword(self):
    BuiltIn().import_resource('${EXECDIR}/Resources/HealthCheck.robot')
    BuiltIn().run_keyword('keyword1')

def aaa_radius(self):
    BuiltIn().import_resource('${EXECDIR}/Resources/HealthCheck.robot')
    BuiltIn().run_keyword('keyword2')

def custom_keyword(self,file):
    abr = Process(target=importABR.abr1_keyword(self)).start()
    radius = Process(target=importABR.aaa_radius(self)).start()
    with open(str(file), 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerows(abr)
        writer.writerows(radius)
```

Here, customer_keyword function I am calling in robot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't do it that way. You should look for a library that implements keyword parallel execution, such as [Async](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-async/).

Also you can run test (actually suites) in parallel using [Pabot](https://pabot.org/).

Comment: Thnaks for the assist!!!Checking for Async library to run parallel execution of keywords